# Using TableLayout to perform like expandable listview

Tags: java, android, android-layout, expandablelistview

> Is it possible to use TableLayout to get the same function of
>   ExpandableListView by dynamically adding the rows(when expanding) and
>   removing the rows ( when hiding) ?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, but why would you want to re-invent the wheel like that?

Comment: @Barak because i need to apply different layouts for each group items in the expandable listview. So i thought of doing it with TableLayout.

Comment: can you suggest me some examples?

Comment: Or is it possible to add different tablelayouts to each group in expandable listview? i need to set onClickListener for each rows in that table too.

Comment: Iam trying the same, have solved the issue.